# How to unable checkboxes when there are two checked already?

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox

I have three checkboxes as below:

```
viewof year_range = 
Inputs.checkbox(["2020", "2021", "2022"], {value: ["2020", "2021"], label: "Year Range"})
```

How can I get just two inputs?

For example, if there are two values selected, the third checkbox gets unable to be checked, and when I uncheck one of the two selected, the others get able to be checked.

so how to add condition here to disable the third one?

Comment: Can you create some fiddle to mimic your issue ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
(See comments in the code for some explanation.)

```js
const boxesContainer = document.getElementById("boxes-container"),
  boxes = boxesContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");
let checkedCount = 0; // Tracks number of checked boxes

// Calls handleCheckboxes when user checks/unchecks a box
boxesContainer.addEventListener("change", handleCheckboxes);


function handleCheckboxes({target}){
  // Prevents handling any irrelevant events
  if(target.attributes["type"]?.value != "checkbox"){ return; }

  // If a box just became checked, increments count, and if count
  //   has now reached 2, disables the remaining unchecked box
  if(target.checked){
    if(++checkedCount == 2){
      for(const box of boxes){
        if(box.checked != true){
          box.setAttribute("disabled", "");
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // A box just became unchecked, so decrements count, and if count
  //   has now been reduced to 1, enables all boxes
  else if(--checkedCount == 1){
    for(const box of boxes){
      box.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes-container">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2020"/>2020</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2021"/>2021</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2022"/>2022</label>
</div>
```

Comment: great thanks. 
just one more thing, how can I access the values? when I checked two of them can I have a list of values?

Comment: Sure, an input element would be of little use if we couldn't access its value. It's available in the `.value` property. The simplest way to collect them might be to loop through the boxes again and conditionally push each value to an array.

Comment: I could get the value like this:

  `var arrayName = [];
for(const box of boxes){
  if(box.checked == true){
      arrayName.push(box.value)` 

but I don't know how to return it and use as global value? because I have it in the handleCheckboxes function

Comment: I should say that I am using Observable. so, all the first code you send I got it as a variable. so I want that variable have the array I created

Comment: I mean is there anyway to have something like this `boxesContainer.addEventListener("change", array= handleCheckboxes);` to return my array through that function?